# limit for dashboard run as as the logged-in user

Tags: governorlimits, dashboard

After I've created a certain number of dashboards set *for running as the logged-in user*, Salesforce tells me I cannot create another one.
In order to solve this problem I deleted 2 of those ones and.... it still doesn't let me save my last Dashboard.

`Error: You reached the limit for dashboards run as the logged-in user.`

Is it just a matter of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes this happens because you still need to empty those dashboards from the Recycle Bin. After you do that try to save the new dashboard again. Some [further explanation on this is available here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003688&language=en_US).
If you're comfortable running custom SOQL queries you can see the list of Dynamic Dashboards in your org by running this query:

`SELECT DeveloperName, Type, Id FROM Dashboard 
WHERE Type IN ('LoggedInUser', 'MyTeamUser')
ORDER BY DeveloperName Asc`

Comment: Actually this time it worked just deleting other dashboard. I think it was just a matter of time for SF to update the informations. Nevertheless.... Your answer is a good one, and often useful for other cases!

Comment: @AndreaIanni௫ thank you! I'm glad you were able to get your dashboard saved.